# How to make newest version of Python the default or first in path

Tags: python, upgrade, pythonpath, system-variable

I have installed a new version of Python, so I want to make sure when Python is invoked that version is first in my path. So, now on my 'C' drive I have "Python27" and "Python32" (old and new version, respectively).

When I type "python" in the command line I get "Python 2.7". Using control panel I have changed the "path" and "pythonpath" user variables (from 'C:\Python27' to 'C:\Python32') and to be sure I have reload the system. It still does not work. Does anyone have any idea how I can force the system to use the new version of Python?

**ADDED**

May be this is important. When I go to the 'Python32' directory and type in command line 'python', I do get the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I know you say you've updated `%PATH%`. However, from the description of the symptoms it is almost certain that `c:\Python27` still appears on the `%PATH%` instead of (or before) `c:\Python32`.

To diagnose, start `cmd.exe` and type `set`. Then locate `PATH` and see what Python directories it contains and in what order.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I put the dirs to all installed Python versions in `%PATH%`, but changed the executable names for all but the 'default' version. E.g., I have a `C:\Python26\Python.exe`, `C:\Python27\Python27.exe` and a `C:\Python32\Python32.exe`. This way I can easily start any version from the command line.